# How to run libraries as a docker container service?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, docker, dockerfile, pypandoc

I wanted to use PyPandoc as a service (In Docker container).

I installed "docker pull msabramo/pypandoc".
It creates an image but I don't know how to use it (input to Docker container and get output).
What am I supposed to type from there?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to follow the instruction from [`hub.docker.com/r/msabramo/pypandoc/`](https://hub.docker.com/r/msabramo/pypandoc/)

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/source -it msabramo/pypandoc
```

That opens a bash session, in which you have your project in `/source` (mounted from your current host folder `pwd`)

You can then type:

```
import pypandoc
output = pypandoc.convert('somefile.md', 'rst')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I wanted to run like this... [link](https://github.com/mrded/pandoc-as-a-service)                                           curl -H "Content-Type: text/markdown" -X POST -d "# hello" http://localhost/html

Comment: @user7429130 OK... then what is the issue?